# Pointer changes after function call

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function that adds processes to a vector of object `Process`.
I have a private member called `Process * CPU` and my goal is to have it point to the first process I add to the vector. I can keep on adding more processes, but CPU should still point to the first one.

```
void DiskSched::addProcess() {    
      if (isEmpty()) {
         // If CPU is empty, the new process will automatically go to the CPU
         Process newProcess;
         newProcess.setProcessProperties(0,Header::PID,++Header::TIME);
         CPU = &newProcess; // assigning the first process to the CPU

         cout << endl;
         cout << "Process object: " << newProcess.getPageNum() << " "<< newProcess.getPID() << " " << newProcess.getTimeStamp() << endl;
         cout << "CPU pointer: " << CPU->getPageNum() << " " << CPU->getPID() << " " << CPU->getTimeStamp() << endl;

       }
       else {
        // ....
       }
}
```

The "CPU pointer" will be the same as the Process object one because it's in the function and that is what I want. I get:

```
0 1 1
0 1 1
```

I have another function that just outputs the properties of the CPU:

```
void DiskSched::currentCPU() {
   cout << endl;
   cout << "Page #: " << CPU->getPageNum() << endl
        << "PID: " << CPU->getPID() << endl
        << "Timestamp: " << CPU->getTimeStamp() << endl;
}
```

When I call currentCPU, the properties of my CPU pointer is not the same. I get:

```
Page #: 1595623976 (should be 0)
PID: 32767 (should be 1)
Timestamp: 1595624103 (should be 1)
```

I believe when I'm assigning `CPU` to the address of the first object in my vector, it's just for that function call and it doesn't actually change my private `CPU` pointer. How can I fix this?

Comment: `CPU = &newProcess;` is assigning the address of a local variable. When that function ends, so does the lifetime of that local variable. I see no evidence of a vector in use in your example. Perhaps it needs more detail. [mcve]

Comment: What @RetiredNinja is saying is that you've stored in `CPU` the address of `newProcess`. But as soon as you exit the scope of the `if` statement, `newProcess` ceases to exist (since it's a local variable). So `CPU` now stores the address `newProcess` used to be stored in but no longer is. Any attempt to use the value stored in `CPU` is doomed.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that. Thank you both! There was a push to the vector, I somehow erased that when pasting the code onto the website.